# Should I be worried about a dark red spot on my acorn squash?

Tags: food-safety, spoilage, squash

[image]

When I split open the acorn squash, there was a large blood-red spot with small white spots in the middle. My best guess is it's rot or mold. I cut it out, leaving plenty of the normal golden flesh around it, but is the rest of the acorn squash contaminated? The flesh smells and looks normal everywhere else.
And any ideas what it is? That color is disturbing :/